# Creating drop down of text boxes using bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

So i have multiple elements of name(the language differs)

And I wanted to make it in a table and it would look something like this:
[image: What i want to make]

I did it by doing something like this:

```
<td>
    <div class="dropdown">
        <a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" style="text-align: center">
           Name<b class="caret"></b>
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
           <li style="text-align: center">
               Name
               {{ Form::text('name'.$forumCategory->id,$forumCategory->name,array('class' => 'change')) }}
           </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</td>
```

It has places for text input. But every time I click the box the menu disappears. How could I get around it or maybe do it differently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the answer for this is:

```
<td>
    <div class="dropdown">
        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#titleEdit" style="text-align: center">LV {{ Form::text('name'.$forumCategory->id,$forumCategory->name,array('class' => 'change')) }}
          <b class="caret"></b>
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu mt10" id="titleEdit">
           <li style="text-align: center">RU {{ Form::text('name'.$forumCategory->id,$forumCategory->name,array('class' => 'change')) }}</li>
           <li class="mt10" style="text-align: center">EN {{ Form::text('name'.$forumCategory->id,$forumCategory->name,array('class' => 'change')) }}</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</td>
```

Im using blade templating(laravel) for this so in place of `{{ Form::text('name'.$forumCategory->id,$forumCategory->name,array('class' => 'change')) }}` you put your `<input>` tag with the required attributes.

And it looks somthing like this then:

[image: it looks like this]

You can type in it, the menu opens when text box is selected or the caret is pressed.

EDIT !-------------------------!

Added a little fix, removed the href for the  tags because if they are left the page jumps to the top when they are clicked.